# CodeIgniter: Loading multiple Controllers within another Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I'm fairly new to CodeIgniter and trying to do the following:

I've got a model App, Attribute and Sound.

In the create method of the App-Controller, I'm trying to save Attributes and Sounds. I'm using the following (basically working) approach:

```
$this->load->library('../controllers/attributes');
$this->attributes->create('value1', 'value2');
```

This works perfectly, the attributes controller is found in `$this->attributes`.

Now I'm trying to do the same for the sounds:

```
$this->load->library('../controllers/sounds');
$this->sounds->create('value3', 'value4');
```

This doesn't work, because the sounds controller is saved in `$this->attributes->sounds` instead of `$this->sounds`.

Edit:

```
$this->load->library(array('../controllers/sounds', '../controllers/attributes'));
```

Results in the same problem, it'll turn into `$this->sounds` and `$this->sounds->attributes`.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You cannot load controller within controllers using codeigniter on it's own I would use Codeigniter HMVC.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using models for these? Controllers shouldn't be loaded in as libraries.